# Обратиться к элементу jQuery на странице по ID в котором есть часть текста

Tags: javascript, jquery

Суть вопроса такова, есть элемент на с id="v-cancel-1041", как я могу через jQuery обратиться к этому элементу? Но проблема в том, что я знаю только то, что id="v-cancel- а остальные цифры генерируются кодом. То есть я не знаю точный id, только часть

Есть ли возможность через фильтр как то найти этот элемент? Можно и на чистом JS если на jquery нету вариантов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, [CSS селекторы по атрибутам](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) вполне работают.

```js
$("div[id^='v-cancel']").text("работает!")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="v-cancel-1041"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, работает идеально. Не знал что можно и так не четко указывать селектор

Answer (score 1):

В jQuery, `$` - это просто функция, которая помимо прочего, в качестве аргумента принимает и обычную строку, которую обработает как CSS-селектор. А конкатенацию строк еще не отменяли)

```
let code = 1041; // откуда-то прилетело число...

$("#v-cancel-" + code)
```

Соответственно, на JS это выглядит так:

```
document.getElementById("v-cancel-" + code);
document.querySelector("#v-cancel-" + code);
```

Comment: Проблема в том что я уже со страницы получаю атрибут этого элемента, поэтому не могу знать откуда оно прилетит и как найти его вообще

Comment: @ВладимирТытыкало «а остальные цифры генерируются кодом» (c) - ну вы же откуда-то узнали, что оно существует. Значит где-то это число записывается? Откуда можно было бы получить к нему доступ)